# Assigning values to matrix(a list of lists) in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to have a N x N matrix in SWI-Prolog with values of every element assigned in the range  1..9. Here's my code

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
n_matrix(N, Rows) :-
   length(Rows, N),
   Rows ins 1..9,
   maplist(length_(N), Rows).

length_(L, Ls) :- length(Ls, L).
```

It gives the following error:

1 ?- n_matrix(4,R).

`ERROR: Type error:`integer' expected, found `[_G2363,_G2366,_G2369,_G2372]'`

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. But how could we go around the problem of assigning then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the domain assignment `Xs ins 1..9,` should be applied on each Row in Rows, while you're applying to the 'matrix'... I would write

```
n_matrix(N, Rows) :-
   length(Rows, N),
   maplist(row(N), Rows).

row(N, Row) :-
   length(Row, N),
   Row ins 1..9.
```

As an alternative - less readable imo -

```
n_matrix(N, Rows) :-
   bagof(Row, C^(between(1, N, C), length(Row, N), Row ins 1..9), Rows).
```

Comment: Yep. I had the right answer, just was careless with my row/column naming.